# Snowflake VBA Excel Connection Issues

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CEBk.png)

I am getting this error (see attached image) when trying to connect to Snowflake via Excel VBA.

This is my connection string:

```
sConnString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=YESDATA;HDR=Yes;pwd=*****"
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? I am using Windows 10 Pro and 64 bit version of Excel. The Snowflake ODBC driver is installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL connection is failing because it cannot be validated.  There are three cURL options that you can try changing to verify this:

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS

If changing (any of) these to false allows your connection to succeed, then you have identified the nature of the issue, however you should not then leave them set to false permanently unless you do not care about the security of your connection.

If self-signed SSL certificates are involved, this is likely to be the root cause.